# Avoid destroying sound when it's paused

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I'm currently working on dialogue system that will handle playing npc quotes and show subtitles to them. I've run into problem with engine destroying paused sounds.

How does it look like:

So I've created function that creates sound and it looks like this:

```
UAudioComponent* UAudioController::Sound2D(UObject* WorldContextObject, class USoundBase* Sound, float VolumeMultiplier, float PitchMultiplier, float StartTime)
{
    if (!Sound)
    {
        return nullptr;
    }

    UAudioComponent* AudioComponent = UGameplayStatics::CreateSound2D(WorldContextObject, Sound, VolumeMultiplier, PitchMultiplier, StartTime);
    AudioComponent->bIsUISound = false;
    PlaybackPositionMap.Add(AudioComponent, 0.f);
    BindDelegates(AudioComponent);
    AudioComponent->Play(StartTime);
    return AudioComponent;
}
```

As you can see there is PlaybackPositionMap which is basicly TMap with UAudioComponent and float. I'm using it to track time played. There is also function called BindDelegates() which looks like this:

```
void UAudioController::BindDelegates(UAudioComponent* AudioComponent)
{
    if (AudioComponent->IsValidLowLevel())
    {
        AudioComponent->OnAudioPlaybackPercent.AddDynamic(this, &UAudioController::SavePlaybackPosition);
        AudioComponent->OnAudioFinished.AddDynamic(this, &UAudioController::SoundFinished);
    }
}
```

First bind for AudioPlaybackPercent just measures time played and saves it in my map. Second bind signals me that sound finished playing which is important for me nad which is root of my problem.

PROBLEM:
When I'll use SetPaused node in blueprint after some time I'll get message that my sound finished playing even if it didn't. I've checked it and AudioComponent is just destroyed. I've tried doing this:

```
AudioComponent->AddToRoot();
```

but it crashed my editor. Is there any other way to approach it? Is it fault of using CreateSound2D?

Answer (score 0):

`CreateSound2D` sets `bAutoDestroy` to `true` on creating the `AudioComponent`.
You can set it to `false` in your function to avoid having it destroyed.

You might also want to take a look at the other options listed in `AudioComponent.h`.